# Specify custom value for From field when composing a message

Tags: email, evolution

In the Evolution email client, how can I specify a custom value for the From value just for the message I'm composing?

My email account is common to the various different email addresses I use. When composing a new message, or a reply, I often want to set the context-relevant email address in the From field for my message.

I don't see a way to do it in Evolution; the only obvious option is to set the email address for *all* messages from the account. That doesn't meet the requirement. I want the default value as it is, *and* still need to sometimes change the From field on a message. How to do that?